# How to get the $meta_type given the $object_id

Tags: terms, term-meta

I'm trying to copy meta data from a term to an object when that term is assigned to the object by way of `wp_set_object_terms()`.  When I hook into `set_object_terms`, I am able to obtain the desired `$meta_key` and `$meta_value` (as well as the desired `$object_id`, which is passed via the hook).  The problem lies when I go to copy the term meta to the object.  This can only be done by way of `update_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)` because I do not know the `$meta_type` (specifically, I cannot use `update_post_meta()`, `update_comment_meta()`, `update_user_meta()`, etc).

Given the `$object_id` (and a *WP_Term* object), how does one go about determining the `$meta_type` to be passed to `update_metadata()`?  Specifically, I am looking to calculate a **string value** equal to *post*, *comment*, *term*, *user*, or any other string that identifies an object type with an associated meta table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given the `$object_id` (and a *WP_Term* object), how does one go about
> determining the `$meta_type` to be passed to `update_metadata()`?

Unfortunately, that is not possible because each object has its own table and therefore the same ID (1, 2, 3, etc.) could refer to a post, comment, term, etc.

So that's why we have different functions which query different tables based on the object ID (that we pass to the function) **and** type (that is in the function name), e.g. `get_post()` for retrieving a post object and `get_comment()` for retrieving a comment object.

> This can only be done by way of `update_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)` because I do not know the
> `$meta_type` (specifically, I cannot use `update_post_meta()`,
> `update_comment_meta()`, `update_user_meta()`, etc).

I don't know, either. But looking at the WordPress database structure (and diagram like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWBrd.png)), I think `$object_id` *should* always be a **post ID**, therefore `$meta_type` would then be `post`. And here's why:

- Of all the core object types in WordPress, only posts that would have terms-taxonomy relationships (i.e. users for example, do not have taxonomies).
- `wp_set_object_terms()` inserts term-taxonomy relationship into the `wp_term_relationships` table which (does not have an `object_type` field, and) has two primary keys — `object_id` and `term_taxonomy_id`. So that means, the object IDs there should belong to the *same object type*.

<sub>PS: I copied the diagram/image above from [here](https://wpdatatables.com/wordpress-database-schema/) where at the time of writing (this answer), that article was last updated in August 2021. There's also an official one on the (yes, outdated) [Codex website](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)..</sub>

So in summary, I don't know how, but I might use `if ( get_post( $object_id ) ) { copy the term meta to the post meta table }`..